# How do I pass a variable from a function to another in C++?

Tags: c++, function, variables, pass-by-reference

```
#include <iostream>

const double pi{3.14};

double radius()
{
    std::cout << "What is the radius of your circle?\n";
    double radius{};
    std::cin >> radius;

    return radius;
}

void circumfrence()
{
    double circumfrence{2 * pi * radius()};

    std::cout << "The circumfrence of your circle is " << circumfrence << std::endl;
}

void area()
{
    double area{pi * radius() * radius()}
}
```

I am trying to pass the variable `radius` from `radius()` to `area()`, and can't seem to figure it out. I know that right now my code will run `radius()` twice, and that is not what I want. I am practicing using functions, so that is why I am not just asking for the radius in the local scope of `area()`.

I tried to do  the following to try to pass the argument by reference, but I kept getting an "identifier is undefined" error in my other functions.

```
void radius(double& radius)
{
    std::cout << "What is the radius of your circle?\n";
    double radius{};
    std::cin >> radius;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be a brain-fart because I think you already knew how to do this:

```
void area()
{
    double r{radius()};
    double area{pi * r * r};
    std::cout << "The area is " << area << "\n";
}
```

Comment: you could also choose to make `r` an input parameter of the function `area`

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should not name your local variables the same as the functions that declare them. Use unique names for your variables.

Now, in your first snippet, simply save the return value of `radius()` to a local variable, then use it as needed:

```
void area()
{
    double l_radius{radius()};
    double l_area{pi * l_radius * l_radius};

    std::cout << "The area of your circle is " << l_area << std::endl;
}
```

In your second snippet, simply remove the local variable, and read into the parameter directly:

```
void radius(double& a_radius)
{
    std::cout << "What is the radius of your circle?\n";
    std::cin >> a_radius;
}

void circumference()
{
    double l_radius{};
    radius(l_radius);

    double l_circumference{2 * pi * l_radius};

    std::cout << "The circumference of your circle is " << l_circumference << std::endl;
}

void area()
{
    double l_radius{};
    radius(l_radius);

    double l_area{pi * l_radius * l_radius};

    std::cout << "The area of your circle is " << l_area << std::endl;
}
```